# Movie where a time traveller goes back in time with his Recreational Vehicle (RV)

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

The plot is about a younger man, who travels back in time. Somehow he's transported back in time with his RV. He appears in the middle ages.

I remember only the ending. It shows a mural of his RV with an antenna.

The language might be in German, but I'm not sure.

The movie is from late eighties or early nineties. I saw it in the early nineties and it was most likely a few years old.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SciFi.SE! Does he use the RV to go back in time? Could you please have a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: thank you fez! i'm not sure if he uses the RV or is just transported back in time with it. I just remember the RV on the mural, so it travelled back in time with him for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[The Miracle in Valby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miracle_in_Valby)*** (1989).

> *The Miracle in Valby* (Swedish: *Miraklet i Valby*) is a 1989 Danish-Swedish drama film written and directed by Åke Sandgren, and starring Jakob Katz, Troels Asmussen, Lina Englund, and Amalie Ihle Alstrup. The film was produced by Nordisk Film, won the awards for Best Film, Best Director and Best Screenplay at the Guldbagge Award.

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097890/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) has a decent plot summary:

> **14 year old Sven is a technical genius, who has rebuilt an old caravan into a radio communication center.** Via radio he is in contact with his father, who works at a big ship at the other side of the globe. One day the radio communication is suddenly interrupted by something which sounds like a Latin mass. In school Sven attends a lesson about radio-astronomy. The teacher explains that astronomers can receive radio waves that are thousand years old. Sven understands that the Latin mass he heard was transmitted to him from another age. He gets curious and starts making experiments by connecting his radio kit to bigger aerials. **When he sits in the caravan together with his friends Bo and Petra, they not only hear the Latin mass on his radio, but the whole caravan is turned into a time-machine that brings them to the Middle Ages.** They get in trouble with some warriors, who capture Petra, while Sven and Bo escape with the help of their time-machine. The two boys have to go back to the Middle Ages once more to rescue Petra, but this time Sven's little sister Hanna has sneaked into the caravan as well. In the Middle Ages some holy men finds Hanna and the caravan, which they think are sent from Heaven. After a sacred ceremony they let the children go, but the event stays in their memory as the Miracle in Valby.

And here's an image of the mural you described:

[image]

Comment: This is it, you're incredible!